# Vertical bar positioning HTML

Tags: html

okay hello guys, i just came a cross a problem that i don't know how to solve. Pic 1 shows the current situation. I want the orange/yellow div to be more like pic 2. Does anyone know how i may do this?, should i place the navbar into a block and place the div after so it desplays as pic 2?

## Pic 1

[image]

## Pic 2

[image]

```css
/*--------Menu--------*/

.Gnav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.Gnav li {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  border-bottom: none;
}
 
.Gnav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
}
 
.Gnav a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.FoodMenu {
  color: orange;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  
}

.DrinksMenu {
  color: orange;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.Menu {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.VerticalLineMenu {
  border-left: 3px solid orange;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!--Menu-->
<div id="menu"></div>
<h2 class="text-center" style="padding-top:10px;">Menu</h2>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="Menu">
        <nav class="Gnav">
            <h1 class="FoodMenu">Food</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Food/Sandwiches.html">Sandwiches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Food/Pizza.html">Pizza</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Food/Pasta.html">Pasta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Food/Burgers.html">Burgers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Food/Salad.html">Salad</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Food/Steaks.html">Steaks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Food/Kids.html">Kids Menu</a></li>
                </ul>
            <h1 class="DrinksMenu">Drinks</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Drinks\Soft Drinks.html">Soft Drinks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Drinks\Beer.html">Beer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Drinks\Wine.html">Wine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Drinks\Champagne.html">Champagne</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Drinks\Coffee.html">Coffee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="NavMenu/Drinks\Water.html">Water</a></li>     <!--bara en bild ist för en tab-->
                </ul>
                <div class="VerticalLineMenu"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>


  <h1 class="pMenu">Feel free to search for your favorite food, a simple click...</h1>
```

Comment: Be clear what you are asking. Put the details in the body of the question, not hidden in links. You probably should review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might want to use `HTML table`

Answer (score 0):

in css change

`.VerticalLineMenu {
  border-left: 3px solid orange;
  height: 500px;
}`

to

```
.VerticalLineMenu {
  border-top: 3px solid orange;
  width: 500px;
}
```

and in html cut and past this code further up

or add to the css

```
position : absolute;
top:0;
```

=

```
.VerticalLineMenu {
  border-left: 3px solid orange;
  height: 500px;
position : absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but it didn't really solve my problem. I was the vertical line to be in pic 2, like a line 200px away from the menu. with your code width 500 didnt make any sense and it was placed at the top of the webpage. here is a live version of it. https://elevarbetensys.se/SY15/MS15/First/index.html